# Link images in MS Word (like in Adobe Indesign)

Tags: microsoft-word

I am looking for a way to show images (.png or .jpg) by a link (not embedding the image in the file) with a Microsoft Word document. I want to link to images on my drive just as is possible in Adobe InDesign.

Images refer to high-resolution bitmaps, for example 8K png files. Currently, those are too big to handle them efficiently in word (large .doc files, long copy-pasting).

Linking means both connecting to a file (refreshing if it changes) and displaying it inside the Word document as if it was embedded.

Perhaps there is an addin for that?

Comment: Thanks, I meant high-resolution images, not icons.

Comment: Thanks one more time - it's also about displaying it inside the document, not just directing to the source.

Comment: "You can insert objects this way from any program that supports the technology of linking and embedding objects (object linking and embedding, or OLE)" as per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linked-objects-and-embedded-objects-0bf81db2-8aa3-4148-be4a-c8b6e55e0d7c - on a hunt for OLE-smart graphics apps as I type

Comment: That would be great, I saw that OLE should be supported, but I couldn't get it to work. When trying to insert .png file it came up only as file icon. When trying to insert .pdf it got embedded, not linked.